# Tensorflow initialization lags

Tags: python, tensorflow

Attempting to use a trained model for prediction, it appears that initializing the session takes a while. Is there a fast way to get model prediction from the command line?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import time

graph = tf.Graph()                                                    
with graph.as_default():
    t0 = time.time()                                                                                                 
    sess = tf.Session()                                                                                              
    t1 = time.time()                                                                                                 
print('time: %s ' % (t1-t0))                                                                                                     

>>> time: 11.136097192764282
```

Comment: did you write above code tf.initialize_all_variables() ?

Comment: no, adding it throws an error "Object was never used"

Comment: could you paste your all code ?

Comment: that's everything

Comment: it's taken for me time: 0.0029993057250976562

Comment: good to know, any thoughts on how to debug?

Comment: i am using jupyter maybe because of that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151616/discussion-between-ssjadon-and-beyhan-gul).

Answer (score 0):

Use frozen protobuf model - [blog](https://medium.com/towards-data-science/building-a-real-time-object-recognition-app-with-tensorflow-and-opencv-b7a2b4ebdc32)